# What are the side effect of running multiple instances of logstash in roundrobin/failover on the client?

Tags: logstash

I would like to run multiple instances of logstash to improve persistence and high availability. Are there side effects to run multiple instances of logstash in roundrobin/failover on the client?

Comment: Run multiple instances on the same server or multiple servers with logstash?

Comment: @leandrojmp multiple instances on the same server

Comment: Running multiple instances on the same server does not make much sense as they will share and compete for the resources, it won't give you any advantages from running just one instance.

Comment: @leandrojmp  and multiple instances on different servers?

Comment: For the client shipping data to logstash it makes no difference where the server is, it just needs to be able to reach the server. Some clients, like filebeat, can load balance between the servers without any problem, depending on how you will ship the logs, you will need to implement a way to load balance if the client does not support, but you need to provide more information about your issue.